# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte. How to fix it

Tags: python

When I run this code I get an error:

```
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

My code:

```
import http.client
import json
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.remove.bg")
apikey = os.getenv('apikey')
imageurl = 'https://www.remove.bg/example-hd.jpg'
payload = json.dumps({
  "image_file_b64": "",
  "image_url": imageurl,
  "size": "preview",
  "type": "auto",
  "type_level": "1",
  "format": "auto",
  "roi": "0% 0% 100% 100%",
  "crop": False,
  "crop_margin": "0",
  "scale": "original",
  "position": "original",
  "channels": "rgba",
  "add_shadow": False,
  "semitransparency": True,
  "bg_color": "",
  "bg_image_url": ""
})
headers = {
  'X-API-Key': apikey,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
conn.request("POST", "/v1.0/removebg", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

How to fix it?

I also tried doing this, but it didn't help. But the error has changed.

if i replace this

```
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

with this

`print(data)`

i have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exdjq.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to their [API documentation](https://www.remove.bg/api#get-started), the response content is the result image. So you shouldn't try to decode it like it was text.
Just do `with open("image.png", "w") as file: file.write(data)`.